# React Component PropType is defined but prop is never used eslint error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, eslint, typescript-eslint

For some reason I am getting the "PropType is defined but prop is never used" lint error in the code bellow:

```
type LinkType = {
  name: string; //PropType is defined but prop is never
  href: string; //PropType is defined but prop is never
  target?: string; //PropType is defined but prop is never
  rel?: string; //PropType is defined but prop is never
};

type MyComponentPropsType = {
  links?: LinkType[];
};

function MyComponent({ links }: MyComponentPropsType): ReactElement {
  return (
    <ul>
      {links.map(({ name, href, target, rel }: LinkType) => ( //I'm using the type here
        <li key={name}>
          <a href={href} rel={rel} target={target}>
            {name}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

For some reason I get the "PropType is defined but prop is never used" and I am using these types, so I want understand why I getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

// This is because you define the type as an object, and in .map you use destructurization. Change your code as follows:

```
type LinkType = {
  name: string; //PropType is defined but prop is never
  href: string; //PropType is defined but prop is never
  target?: string; //PropType is defined but prop is never
  rel?: string; //PropType is defined but prop is never
};

type MyComponentPropsType = {
  links?: LinkType[];
};

function MyComponent({ links }: MyComponentPropsType): ReactElement {
  return (
    <ul>
      {links.map((link: LinkType) => ( //I'm using the type here
        <li key={name}>
          <a href={href} rel={rel} target={target}>
            {name}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```